# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService -> firefox -> plugin selenium grid jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, plugins

I have problem with plugin selenium grid in jenkins.
Sesion not created  on firefox.

[INFO] Running TestSuite

lut 01, 2022 11:20:48 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities firefox
INFO: Using `new FirefoxOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.firefox()`

Błąd załadowania przeglłądarki: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'SIA-TEST-W10-01', ip: '172.25.20.111', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 721 milliseconds podana została przeglądarka o parametrze:firefox
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'SIA-TEST-W10-01', ip: '172.25.20.111', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 721 milliseconds
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
at

Comment: FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
                options.setCapability("platform", Platform.WINDOWS);
                options.setCapability("marionette", true);
                options.setCapability("firefox" , true);
                capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
                this.driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(hub, options));

Comment: The problem was plugin jenkins selenium who was not suporrted for 6 years on firefox. We change plugin from github source.https://github.com/jenkinsci/selenium-plugin